Spooky, scary, sequence
What three numbers come next in this sequence?
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 19…
This sequence is not mathematical.
Good luck solving this puzzle! 
Hint:

 Look back at the title…

Hint 2:

 This sequence is Gold.


Would the [tag:knowledge] tag apply here?

Is it a finite sequence?

@sarsaparilla Yes, it is a finite sequence.


 The song "Spooky Scary Skeletons" (that the title alludes to) is by Andrew Gold (that the second hint alludes to.) Let's take the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. words of that song and see if there's anything in common...


 spooky (1), scary (2), skeletons (3), send (4), shivers (5), spine (8), shrieking (9), skulls (10), shock (12), soul (14), seal (15), spooky (19).

I think there's a common thread there, don't you? That would make the next three in the sequence:

 scary (20), skeletons (21), speak (22).


How do the hints play into the solution? The first one is a bit obvious, but I'm missing the second one. Perhaps you should consider editing that information into your answer.

@BlueHerring The significance of the second hint is in the first spoiler block.

Ah, don't know how I missed that ;)

Happens to the best of us!
